# check radio button in angular 2 when there is ngModel

Tags: angular, radio-button

In my Angular 2 project there is `ngModel` and the radio button doesn't check it

```
<input type="radio" id="user" name="user" value="RETAIL" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" check>
```

But when I cut the `ngModel` it check

```
<input type="radio" id="user" name="user" value="RETAIL check>
```

But I can't cut it because I need `ngModel`, is there another way to check radio button on the load page with `ngModel`?

Comment: what is myRadio?

Comment: The identification of attribute of ngModel

Comment: what is the value it holds?

Comment: Nothing, I used it to get the value of the cheked radio, but I want that the this radio button is just checked when I load the page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the value of the input element is a string literal, declare it using one of the two following forms:

```
<input type="radio" id="user" name="user" value="My value 1" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" />
<input type="radio" id="user" name="user" [value]="'My value 1'" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" />
```

If the value is not a string literal, use `[value]`:

```
<input type="radio" id="user" name="user" [value]="MyValue1" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" />
```

---

To have the radio button selected by default, you should initialize `myRadio` to the appropriate value:

For a string value:

```
public myRadio: string = "My value 1";
```

For another type of data:

```
public myRadio: MyDataType = MyValue1;
```

---

You see the code at work in **[this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7pSK0A8wjwkdrf3vZXPE?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 2):

You’re missing the binding on the check attribute. 
You just need this

```
<input type=“radio” id=“user” name=“user” value=“RETAIL” [(ngModel)]=“myRadio” [checked]=“true”>
```

I’ve placed the true because you asked for it to be checked upon page load. But instead of true you can put a variable or a condition if you want it to have a bit more logic behind.

You can have a quick look [here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-binding-radiobutton-lists/) to check a bit more options on how to setup a radio button on Angular

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
 <input  type="radio" name="user" [value]="RETAIL" [(ngModel)]="myRadio">
```

Comment: try checked <input type="radio" id="user" name="user" value="RETAIL [(ngModel)]="myRadio" [checked]=“true”>

Comment: @Sajeetharan a small typo in above comment value = "RETAIL"