# Unable to use number input with radio button

Tags: angular, radio-button, kendo-ui-angular2

Below shows that the string value works however if my input is a number it doesn't work.  Any ideas aside from making a variable a string?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <p>Model: {{model | json}}</p>
    NOT WORKING<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" [(ngModel)]="model.foo" kendoRadioButton />
      <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" [(ngModel)]="model.foo" kendoRadioButton />
      <input type="radio" name="foo" value="3" [(ngModel)]="model.foo" kendoRadioButton />

    <br/>
      WORKING<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="bar" value="1" [(ngModel)]="model.bar" kendoRadioButton />
      <input type="radio" name="bar" value="2" [(ngModel)]="model.bar" kendoRadioButton />
      <input type="radio" name="bar" value="3" [(ngModel)]="model.bar" kendoRadioButton />

    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public model = {
        foo: 3,
        bar: "2"
    };
}
```

Comment: Try with `[(ngModel)]="model.foo.toString()"`

Comment: @Emilien ngModel on a method won't work, since Angular will try to do something like `model.foo.toString() = newValue` on update, which is not valid...

Comment: @Random You are absolutely right. I didn't know. Thank you !

Comment: Please check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941071/check-radio-button-in-angular-2-when-there-is-ngmodel

Comment: This was the answer that I used in the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `[(ngModel)]` for two-way binding, you could implement the two-way binding yourself by stringifying the setting, and handling the change events.

Each input for a numeric type would look like this:

```html
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" kendoRadioButton
  [ngModel]="model.foo.toString()" 
  (ngModelChange)="onFooChanged($event)" />
```

Your event handler in your component would look like this:

```js
onFooChanged(value) {
  this.model.foo = parseInt(value);
}
```

Without knowing what's going on behind the scenes with `[(ngModel)]`, I assume it is doing a strict equality check for boolean types such as radio buttons.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3xwmx

#### Creating a reusable input

Creating an event handler per property would quickly get tedious if you have several of these. Alternatively you could create your own component that wraps this functionality.

number-radio.input.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'number-radio-input',
  templateUrl: './number-radio-input.component.html',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, 
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumberRadioInputComponent), 
      multi: true }
  ]
})
export class NumberRadioInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {  
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() value: string;

  model: string;
  private _value: number;
  private onChangeCallback: (value: number) => void = () => { };

  onModelChange(): void {
    this._value = parseInt(this.model, 10);
    this.onChangeCallback(this._value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: number) => void): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}

  writeValue(val: number): void {
    this._value = val;
    this.model = val ? val.toString() : '';
  }
}
```

number-radio-input.component.html

```html
<input type="radio" [name]="name"
  [value]="value"
  [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()" />
```

component.html

```html
<number-radio-input [(ngModel)]="model.foo" value="1" name="foo">
</number-radio-input>
```

You would need to pass in additional properties if you wanted to configure the input differently, but at least this will allow you to bind to your model directly.

Comment: Thanks this works.  However I've a lot of radio buttons, so I'll probably need an onChange method for each.

Comment: However, I ended up using @Vignesh's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941071/check-radio-button-in-angular-2-when-there-is-ngmodel

Comment: Good alternative. I've added another option to my answer, which is a bit more full-blooded if you wanted to create a complex reusable component

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
[value]="1"
```

One-way binding on the "value" property.

As described here:
[How to get radio button value as a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129523/how-to-get-radio-button-value-as-a-number)

Comment: This works if I hardcode the value, but not if the value comes from an array.