# How to get radio button value as a number

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is there a way to get the value of the radio button as an integer? 
I'm submitting a form that but the value that I'm getting from radio buttons is always a string, I've tried many solutions but none of them work.

```
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="note" type="radio"  value='3' >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Advanced</label>
        </div>

 <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="note" type="radio"  value=3 >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Advanced</label>
        </div>
```

here is what i get when i submit the form :

[image]

in order to the web API works, I need to have like this `note : 3`, please help.
[UPDATE]

here's my how i'm submitting the form:

```
this.Myser.AddAll(this.rateform.value.lstrates).subscribe(data => console.log(data) );
```

and this is how i declared my form :

```
this.rateform = this.fb.group({
      lstrates: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          fieldId: [''],
          memberId: [''],
          note: [''],
          fieldName:['']
        }),
      ]),
    });
```

but the problem is , the `note` attribut must be a number. so i dont know how to get it from the radio button as integer, should i create another list and convert it to integer ? or there is a better way ?

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: did you try `[value]="3"` or `[ngValue]="3"`?

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Where is Angular? It looks like a normal form now.

Comment: Can u give stackblitz demo please ?

Comment: the attribute will always be a string the only possible way is to convert it upon submitting the form to whatever that's you want

Comment: guys check my update

Comment: The vale of an input element is always a string, except type="number", type="date". You have to convert string to number manullay by using parseInt or parseFloat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `[value]="3"` and skip `value="3"` in this case, it allows to pass any type as a value including objects etc.

See: [angular doc binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview)

Also you might import `FormsModule` if it wasn't.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ll3ckc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I'm getting : Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ng

Comment: try to import FormsModule for this component.