# Angular 7 - How to bind the value to the radio button

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, angular7, angular-forms

I'm trying to use the radio button on my project but I failed to check the first radio button programmatically.

I had tried the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941071/check-radio-button-in-angular-2-when-there-is-ngmodel), but it is still not working in my code.

Here is my radio button:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" style="padding-right: 0px;">
    <input type="radio" value=1 [checked]="actionUpload == 1" name="uploadAction" [(ngModel)]="actionUpload" (ngModelChange)="choose(1)"> Radio 1
    <input type="radio" value=2 [checked]="actionUpload == 2" name="uploadAction" [(ngModel)]="actionUpload" (ngModelChange)="choose(2)"> Radio 2
</div>
```

and below is my Typescript:

```js
export class Component   implements OnInit  {
  actionUpload:number = 1


  constructor() { 
       //some code here
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      //some code here

  }


  choose(upT:number){
    this.actionUpload = upT
  }
}
```

Here is the result I got, radio 1 is never checked.

[image]

Am I missing something??

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `value=1`, it treats the value as a string.

You can inspect the HTML element and would get this

```
<input _ngcontent-tmu-c101="" type="radio" value="1" name="uploadAction" 
  ng-reflect-value="1" 
  ng-reflect-name="uploadAction" ng-reflect-model="1" 
  class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```

which you would see the value become a string.

You should use the **input binding (the square bracket) with `[value]="1"`**.

```
<input
    type="radio"
    [value]="1"
    name="uploadAction"
    [(ngModel)]="actionUpload"
  />
  Radio 1
  <input
    type="radio"
    [value]="2"
    name="uploadAction"
    [(ngModel)]="actionUpload"
  />
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w7aywc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

While I think `[checked]` and `(ngModelChange)` seem to duplicate (function) when you have used the `[(ngModel)]` (two-way binding).

Either you should use (only) one of these:

1. `[checked]` or
2. `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` or
3. `[(ngModel)]`